# How do I fill my bezier curve shape?

Tags: modeling, workflow, bezier-curves

I'm trying to create legs for my park bench in Blender. The shape is a bit complex to model, so I crafted it using bezier-curves.

[image]

However after selecting "**Both**" as my fill-option the shape fills up invertedly:

[image]

The idea is that the thin shapes get filled with the larger areas remaining open. It feels like regardless of what settings I poke at, nothing changes.

The Bezier-shape is being mirrored on the X-axis through a modifier, using clipping to make sure nothing overlaps.

Any hope of inverting Blenders fill to the reverse effect?

Comment: What you need to do is enter edit mode and create a closed curve that sets the outline of the whole object. Then the fill pattern will be reversed. It seems that you already have one, but make sure that is part of the same curve and it is **closed**

Comment: Yeah, your outline curve is most likely open at some undetermined point. Inspect it point by point, or just close it blindly from the tool shelf button.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the suggestions! I found out that my mirror modifier wasn't melding the center vertices.

To fix my problem I had to delete the modifier, duplicate my Bezier-object, manually delete the center vertices and redefine the broken segments.